# Installed Driver for Evga GTX 970. Can't log in to Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I installed the driver using `apt-get` and restarted my computer, and now when I log in. I get stuck in a loop. The screen shows some funny colours and sends me back to the login screen. Is there any way I could do a system restore back to my old graphics settings? any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login to console and remove proprietary drivers

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

after reboot you should get as it was before.

You can install a driver that supports your adapter by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```